# How to properly kill a function

Tags: jquery, function, jwplayer, die

I have a video player that opens and plays whenever a link is clicked and after two videos are viewed there is a form that appears that allows you to rate the information that was given.

The problem that i'm having is that there is a replay button that appears when the video is completed. I currently have setTimeout in place that does away with the video and it's overlay then runs the rate form function. BUT if the replay button it clicked the setTimeout is still running and midway through the replay of the video the function runs. Here is my code:

**Remove Video Overlay**

```
fnVideoOverlayOff = function () {

    jQuery('#video, #block, .video-closebtn').css('display', 'none');

}
```

**JW Player Code**

```
jwplayer('videoScreen').setup({
        flashplayer: '/assets/js/lib/player.swf',
        allowscriptaccess: "always",
        width:972,
        height:547,
        controlbar: "none",
        autostart: true,
        playlistfile: "/assets/videos/playlist.xml",
        events: {
            onPlaylistItem: function (event) {

                jQuery(document).idleTimer('destroy');

            },
                            onPLay: function (event) {

                            },
            onComplete: function (event) {

                setTimeout(function () {

                    fnVideoOverlayOff();

                }, 10000);

                var clickCount = 0;

                if(jQuery.cookie('clickCount') == 2) {

                    fnRateOverlayOn();

                    jQuery('#video, .video-closebtn').css('display', 'none');

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I would like to Kill **fnVideoOverlayOff();** if the replay button is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store a reference to setTimeout, and call `clearTimeout()` when you want to prevent it from finishing.

```
fnVideoOverlayOffTimer = setTimeout(... 

// and later on when you want to "kill" it,

clearTimeout(fnVideoOverlayOffTimer);`
```

Ideally you would declare `fnVideoOverlayOffTimer` somewhere to keep it off the global scope, but that is optional.